# How to match the forward slash using regex

Tags: java, regex

How to use regex to detect and has the forward slash in path. Also with numbers

Example 
String str = "/urpath/23243/imagepath/344_licensecode/"
I want to use regex to make sure the path is match for numbers with forward slash.
the format match must like this "/23243/"

Any idea guys?

Thanks

Comment: sorry.just an example. Edited

Answer (score 15):

You need to escape the special character `/` by using `\`. However, `\` also is the escaping character used by Java, but you want to pass the symbol itself to Regex, so it escapes for Regex. You do so by escaping the escape symbol with `\\`. So in total you will have `\\/` for the slash.

Use this snippet:

```
String input = ...
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\/23243\\/");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Does match!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Does not match!");
}
```

You can try the Regex itself at **regex101**: [regex101/RkheRs](https://regex101.com/r/RkheRs/1)

Comment: Thanks for reply . how the pattern match only numbers instead of 23243"?

Comment: The pattern change to this  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\/[^0-9]\\/");
but throws errors

Comment: Numbers is \d+. And the forward slash is *not* a special character, so you do not need to escape that. You probably want "/\\d+/" in Java.

Comment: You can use the `digit-class` of Regex for that, it is `\d`. So `\d` matches one digit. `\d\d` matches two digits, you can also use `\d{2}` for that. Or use `\d{1, 4}` which matches one up to four digits. `\d*` matches zero to arbitrary, `\d+` matches one to arbitrary and `\d?` matches zero to one digits.

Comment: Are you sure that `/` is no special character (for regex)? At **regex101** it says '*error, `/` must be escaped - special delimiter*'.

Comment: @vinoth.mohan by using `[^0-9]` you match *everything that is* **not** `0-9`. The `^` negates the content. `[0-9]` can be shortened by using `\d`, it means exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer.Thanks to Mgaert

```
List<String> listArray = new ArrayList<String>();
listArray.add(file.getCanonicalPath());

// Regular expression in Java to check if String is number or not
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/\\d+/");
for (String path: listArray) {
    // Match patter for numbers path
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(path);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Does match!"+ path);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Does Not match!");
    }
}
```