# String.split with a regex and a limit doesn't have expected behaviors

Tags: java, split

I'm working on a simple gadget that divides the xpath of a specific element into smaller pieces by finding the "/"s in the xpath and using java's split method. My code is as follows:

```
String test = "/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[7]/div[3]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]";
String[] split = test.split("/");
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(split[i]);
}
```

It worked, and I got the result:

```
html[1]
body[1]
div[1]
div[7]
div[3]
form[1]
div[1]
div[1]
div[1]
div[2]
div[1]
div[2]
a[1]
```

However, then I decided that I would like to split the xpath into 2 pieces separated by the first "/" in the xpath. I used the split method with a regex and a limit, I changed my code to:

```
 String test = "/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[7]/div[3]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]";
 String[] split = test.split("/",2);
 for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(split[i]);
 }
```

It doesn't work, and gives the result:

```
html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[7]/div[3]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]
```

Thanks to melli-182's comment, I realized that it is actually dividing the string into an empty string and the original string, which is not what I expected. Is there a way to make it work properly?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use `"\\/"` in your regex instead. Check this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038575/how-to-match-the-forward-slash-using-regex

Comment: It worked, but the first String splitted is "" (empty).

Comment: I actually was misreading your question, so disregard my comment. My apologies.

Comment: @AntonH Thank you for the advice. I tried but it didn't seem to work. I realized that it's actually splitting the string into an empty string and the original string. Any idea why it has such behaviors?

Comment: @melli-182 Thank you! I also found out that this might be the reason. Any idea to get rid of the empty string?

Comment: Before you go too far off the rails: HTML is not a regular language.  You can not parse it with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your split is working fine. There should be one empty line printed. 

 The first character in your `test` string is '/' which will split it in "" and "html...". 
Try `split("/", 3)` and it should give you "", "html[1]" and "body[1]....."

Comment: Thank you for the advice

Answer (score 0):

The Split function works ok, and the result is the espected and stated on the [Split Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)

Take into account that the splitted Strings in thye second case are two, the first is an empty String (beacause there is nothing previous to "/") and the second String is what you shared.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a way I can make it work properly by changing the regex?